# Python importing global variables inconsistent behaviour

Tags: python

I'm having trouble importing a variable from a different python file to my current one. I know this has been asked several time previously and I have tried almost all those solutions, but no use.

In file top.py:

```
import sys, getopt, pdb
import argparse

import my_parser

my_parser.start_parse(6)
my_parser.in_out(2)
print "info: ",my_parser.verilog_inps
print "N1 data: ",my_parser.ckt_data["N1"]
```

In file parser.py (the first few lines only):

```
   from collections import defaultdict

ckt_data = {}
global verilog_inps
verilog_inps = []
global verilog_outs
verilog_outs = []
global levels
levels = []
level_dict = defaultdict(list)

class ckt_elements:
    delay = 0
    inp_ = {}
    out_ = {}
    level = 0
    change = False
    prev = {}
    typ_ = ""

def start_parse(a):
    ckt_data["N1"] = a

def in_out(a):
    verilog_inps = [a,a+1,a+2]
```

The strange thing is that I am able to access some variables and I am not able to do so for others (I declared the inaccessible ones global to see if that helps but no)

The aforementioned global variables are being modified in functions in parser.py.

So, my question: Why this strange behaviour? Am I doing something wrong?
Using python 2.7

Please let me know if the question is not clear enough (I am at a loss to explain this better)

**EDIT**

I have solved the issue I am facing by using a global definition file.
In a separate file, I have declared the variables and then imported the file into all relevant files. (using `import globals`)

In any case, I am very curious to know what was wrong with my previous approach.

Comment: @BrenBarn, can you please point me to any link which contains info about how to do this kind of code formatting? I don't get the color highlighting etc...is there some editor like vim in stack exchange?

Comment: Please provide a [short self-contained runnable example](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits your problem. I tried running this code, but I got `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'start_parse'`.

Comment: Re: code formatting, the simplest way to do it is to paste in your code, highlight it, and press ctrl-K. This should indent every line by four spaces, which signals to the markup system to apply color highlighting etc.

Comment: @sanjay: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Perhaps the interpreter is confusing your file `parser.py`, with the built-in module `parser`. Try giving parser.py a name that isn't already used by an existing module, and see if that helps.

Comment: Did you actually do `import parser`, or did you do something like `from parser import *`? The code you've shown doesn't look like it should produce the results you report, but similar code might produce similar errors to what you say. Can you provide a [stripped-down, minimal, runnable example version of your code that produces the error when you run it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @user2357112 I have tried both ways, `from parser import *` and `import parser` but I am still facing the problem...I am creating a stripped down version...

Comment: @user2357112 I am also completely bewildered by this result, I have looked into almost all the answers in this website and others regarding importing global variables

Comment: @Kevin I changed the name to my_parser, but still the same behaviour.

Comment: With the code you've posted, the line you say works shouldn't work and the line you say doesn't work should work. When you use `import parser`, you need to refer to anything from `parser` as `parser.whatever`. When you use `from parser import *`, you need to *not* use the `parser` prefix when accessing things from `parser`.

Comment: @user2357112 Please see latest edit...I have added a runnable code which replicates the exact same behaviour

Comment: @user2357112 My understanding about the `from .. import *` approach was that it creates a copy of the program (which is not required in my case), anyways I am accessing the variables as `parser.something`

Comment: Any alternate approaches apart from the `from * import *` and the `import *` to share variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this function:

```
def in_out(a):
    verilog_inps = [a,a+1,a+2]
```

don't actually affect the global `verilog_inps` variable. It's assigning to a local. You need to put the `global` declaration inside each function where you want to assign to the global variable:

```
def in_out(a):
    global verilog_inps
    verilog_inps = [a,a+1,a+2]
```

or assignments inside a function will cause the Python bytecode compiler to create a local variable with the same name and target the assignment to that variable.

Comment: Thanks! that solves my problem but I also have one more question...initlally, I tried running using `from * import *` and in that case, I had not declared any variables global (since I was importing everything anyway) and I still faced the same issue

Comment: @sanjay: Assignments to the original variables won't be reflected in modules that import the variables with `from` imports, since `from` imports create new, independent variables with the same names as the originals. This can be considered both a reason not to use global variables and a reason not to use `from` imports.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll stay away from creating any global stuff in a particular file...instead I'll create them in a separate global_var file..helps me keep complexity down